# The first DB call is much slower

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

First call at morning takes 15 seconds,

```
FOR EACH ... NO-LOCK:

END.
```

the second call takes only 1,5 seconds.
What causes this delay?
What can I log to identify it?

Even when I restart the DB I can't reproduce the behaviour of the first call.
(In complex queries I measure difference of 15 minutes to 2 seconds)

Comment: That ...-part (as well as table and index-data) is kind of important. Caching is a part of the database of course... But nothing beats a good query matching a good index!

Answer (score 2):

The most likely cause for this will be caching. There are two caches in place:

- The -B buffer pool of the database which caches database blocks in memory. It is a typical observation, that once this cache is warmed up after a restart of the DB server queries are executing much faster. Of course this all depends on the size of your DB and the size of the -B buffer pool. Relatively small databases may fit into a relatively large -B buffer pool in large parts
- The OS disk cache will also play it's part in your observation

Comment: Is it possible to log this cache size with promon or VST's?

Comment: Start with promon activity 5 and check "primary hits" should be 100% or close to it. You can reset by pressing enter, then run query and press enter again. This is per the whole db though so lots of activity isnt perfect but its a start. A good index matching your query is a good approach to take...